# using twist in hosts.allow

Tags: ssh, hosts.deny

At the end of my `hosts.allow` I have the following:

```
ALL : ALL \
 : spawn (echo  "%d" | /usr/bin/mail -s "tcpf\: %d attempt from %h." root) & \
 : severity auth.info \
 : twist /bin/echo "You are not welcome to use %d from %h."`
```

But this appears to simply put that text into my auth.log:

`mail sshd[63546]: twist 12.34.56.789 to /bin/echo "You are not welcome to use sshd from 12.34.56.789."`

On the client side, I only see "Connection closed by remote host" and I do not see the output of the echo. There is nothing in `man -k twist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page for `hosts_options(5)` explains the `twist` command in tcp_wrappers:

> `twist shell_command`
>
> Replace the current process by an instance of the specified shell command, after performing the % expansions described in the `hosts_access(5)` manual page.  Stdin,  stdout  and  stderr are connected to the client process. This option must appear at the end of a rule.

The problem is that SSH is not just a text protocol, but expects some protocol messages and if it does not receive them, it will fail. If you would run the `ssh` in debug mode (`ssh -v`), you would see the following:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: You are not welcome to use sshd from ::1.

ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

So the message is really send, but since it was not correct SSH banner, it fails. There is no simple way how to inject your messages into ssh protocol. You would probably need to accept this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll stop beating my head against this wall.